# Resize and Move Image in Android for Api < 11

Tags: android, image-processing, android-imageview

I've been trying to achieve

1. drag and drop (Move) Api < 11
2. Resize (Larger than original Image)

Is there any external library from which we can resize and move the image in View?

External Materials, Api, Library and Links would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing around with `Matrix()` and `onTouchListener()` had done by work.

```
public class CustomizeActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = "Touch" ;
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
PointF start = new  PointF();
public static PointF mid = new PointF();

public static final int NONE = 0;
public static final int DRAG = 1;
public static final int ZOOM = 2;
public static int mode = NONE;
float oldDist;

private float[] matrixValues = new float[9];


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
iv=new ImageView(this);
iv.setOnTouchListener(t);
}
 OnTouchListener t=new View.OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG" );
            mode = DRAG;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

            oldDist = spacing(event);
            Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
            if (oldDist > 10f) {

                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                midPoint(mid, event);
                mode = ZOOM;
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM" );
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            if (mode == DRAG) {

                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y);
            }
            else if (mode == ZOOM) {

                float newDist = spacing(event);
                Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                if (newDist > 10f) {

                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                }
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

            mode = NONE;
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE" );
            break;
        }

        // Perform the transformation
        view.setImageMatrix(matrix);

        return true; // indicate event was handled
    }

      private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {

        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }
};
  }
```

Comment: Do you know how to implement resizing imageview with dragging points on the corner? Like in MS OFFICE?