# How to give Fluid effect / resize bitmap wrt touch events using opencv4android

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I'm newbie with OpenCV4Android and Android NDK

**Trying to achieve**

Stretch the image with respect to Touch Points on Image.(Putting Hair on Face and stretching it accordingly using touch events Like *'Virtual Make Over Application'*)

**Issues: While using Java**

Implemented warp function on Touch Events by getting Matrix from Bitmap and recomputing them onTouchEvents. But the Image get distorted and whole Matrix gets upside down.

*How can use OpenCV4Android to achieve goal like these?*

#### *Tried to get Mat from Bitmap and Resize the Image. But didn't got any idea How I'm going to proceed further with these?*

Any enlightenment on these would be very helpful.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question: Do you mean you wish to allow the user to drag and resize the hair image? And why do you use "OpenCV4Android " for this? Isn't it for bitmap manipulations?

Comment: Anyway, here are a few links that might help, in case that's what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736318/resize-move-image-in-android-for-api-11 , http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html , http://stackoverflow.com/q/14800037/878126

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through lots of Image Processing Libraries, every one has warpping and morphing effects but none of them having effects on touch points. As many of them suggested you can achieve such things using OpenCV4Android or OpenGL but none of them is my cup of tea.

So In the end implemented Warpping effect with NDK in C.

Here's algorithm which applied to Bitmap Pixels on touch points.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#define LOG_TAG "System.out"
#define LOGD(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGI(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)

int *colorRed;
int *colorGreen;
int *colorBlue;
int *colorsP; //ÏñËØÖµ

int *colorAlpha;
int _width, _height;
jintArray imagecolors;

//²éÕÒ±í
static long SinXDivX_Table_8[(2 << 8) + 1];
double MySin(double x) {
    double absx;
    absx = x;
    if (x < 0)
        absx = -x;
```

WarpView which does the warpping effect on Touch Points:

```
public class WarpView extends View {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("Hello");
    }

    public native int[] warpPhotoFromC(int[] image, int height, int width,
            double max_dist, double orig_x, double orig_y, double cur_x,
            double cur_y);

    private static String TAG = WarpView.class.getSimpleName();

    private Bitmap mBmp;
    private int[] image;
    private int first = 0;
    private int[] colorR;
    private int[] colorG;
    private int[] colorB;
    private Bitmap newBmp;
    private boolean fg = true;
    private Context context;

    private static final int DEFAULT_PAINT_FLAGS = Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG
            | Paint.DITHER_FLAG;
    static Paint mPaint = new Paint(DEFAULT_PAINT_FLAGS);

    public static int HWPPQ = 110;
    public static int MMQFJ = 120;

    private int MODE = MMQFJ;

    // SA VIKALP
//  public ArrayList<WarpViewUndo> mArrayListWarpViewUndo;

    static GestureDetector mGestures;
    static ScaleGestureDetector mScaleGesture;

    private Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();
    private Matrix mInverse = new Matrix();

    private float lastFocusX;
    private float lastFocusY;

    private boolean mIsMove = false;

    // EA VIKALP
    public WarpView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public WarpView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        dest = new RectF(0, 0, 0, 0);

        // SA VIKALP
//      mArrayListWarpViewUndo = new ArrayList<WarpViewUndo>();
        mScaleGesture = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(),
                new ScaleListener());
        mGestures = new GestureDetector(getContext(), new GestureListener());

        mMatrix.setTranslate(5, 5);
        mMatrix.invert(mInverse);
        // EA VIKALP
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (fg) {
            int viewWidht = getWidth();
            int viewHeight = getHeight();
            float scale1 = (float) width / (float) viewWidht;
            float scale2 = (float) height / (float) viewHeight;
            scale = scale1 > scale2 ? scale1 : scale2;
            int xoffset = (viewWidht - (int) (width / scale)) / 2;
            int yoffset = (viewHeight - (int) (height / scale)) / 2;
            dest.set(xoffset, yoffset, (int) (width / scale) + xoffset,
                    (int) (height / scale) + yoffset);// = new RectF(xoffset,
                                                        // yoffset, (int)
                                                        // (width/scale)+xoffset,
                                                        // (int)
                                                        // (height/scale)+yoffset);
            // SA VIKALP
            canvas.drawColor(0x000000);
            canvas.concat(mMatrix);
            // canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            // canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
            // EA VIKALP
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBmp, null, dest, mPaint);

        } else {
            // SA VIKALP
            canvas.drawColor(0x000000);
            canvas.concat(mMatrix);
            // canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            // canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
            // EA VIKALP
            canvas.drawBitmap(newBmp, null, dest, mPaint);
        }
    }

    private double orig_x, orig_y;
    private double mou_dx, mou_dy;
    private double max_dist, max_dist_sq;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int count = 0;
    private double mou_dx_norm;
    private double mou_dy_norm;

    private float scale;
    private RectF dest;
    private double move_x, move_y;
    private int dist = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.max_dist);
    private int line_height = (int) getResources().getDimension(
            R.dimen.warp_line);

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // SA VIKALP
        mScaleGesture.onTouchEvent(event);
        mGestures.onTouchEvent(event);
        // EA VIKALP

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            orig_x = event.getX();
            orig_y = event.getY();
            orig_x = (orig_x - dest.left) * scale;
            orig_y = (orig_y - dest.top) * scale;

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (!mIsMove) { // SA VIKALP ADDED LINE
                max_dist = dist * scale;// Math.hypot(mou_dx, mou_dy);
                if (event.getAction() != 1) {


                    // int m = event.getHistorySize();

                    move_x = event.getX();
                    move_y = event.getY();

                    move_x = (move_x - dest.left) * scale;
                    move_y = (move_y - dest.top) * scale;

                    // if(m > 0){
                    // int i2 = m + -1;
                    // orig_x = (event.getHistoricalX(i2) - dest.left)*scale;
                    // orig_y = (event.getHistoricalY(i2) - dest.top)*scale;
                    // }

                    if (move_x >= 0 && move_y >= 0) {
                            warpPhotoFromC(image, height, width, max_dist, orig_x,
                                    orig_y, move_x, move_y);
                        first++;

                        newBmp.setPixels(image, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
                        fg = false;
                    }
                }
                orig_x = move_x;
                orig_y = move_y;

            } 
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
    // SA VIKALP
//  public void applyWarpUndo(Bitmap bmp) {
//      setWarpBitmap(bmp);
//      Log.i(TAG, "Size : "
//              + mArrayListWarpViewUndo.size()
//              + " last size :"
//              + mArrayListWarpViewUndo.get(mArrayListWarpViewUndo.size() - 1)
//                      .getSize() + 1);
//      
//      for (int i = 0; i < mArrayListWarpViewUndo.size() - (mArrayListWarpViewUndo.get(mArrayListWarpViewUndo.size() - 1).getSize()+1); i++) {
//          if (mArrayListWarpViewUndo.get(i).getMove_x() >= 0 && mArrayListWarpViewUndo.get(i).getMove_y() >= 0) {
//              warpPhotoFromC(mArrayListWarpViewUndo.get(i).getImage(),
//                      mArrayListWarpViewUndo.get(i).getHeight(),
//                      mArrayListWarpViewUndo.get(i).getWidth(),
//                      mArrayListWarpViewUndo.get(i).getMax_dist(),
//                      mArrayListWarpViewUndo.get(i).getOrig_x(),
//                      mArrayListWarpViewUndo.get(i).getOrig_y(),
//                      mArrayListWarpViewUndo.get(i).getMove_x(),
//                      mArrayListWarpViewUndo.get(i).getMove_y());
//
//              newBmp.setPixels(mArrayListWarpViewUndo.get(i).getImage(), 0,
//                      mArrayListWarpViewUndo.get(i).getWidth(), 0, 0,
//                      mArrayListWarpViewUndo.get(i).getWidth(),
//                      mArrayListWarpViewUndo.get(i).getHeight());
//              fg = false;
//          }
//      }
////        Log.i(TAG, "Step Size "+mArrayListWarpViewUndo.size()-1);
//      mArrayListWarpViewUndo.remove(mArrayListWarpViewUndo.size()-2);
//      invalidate();
//  }
    public class ScaleListener implements OnScaleGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Matrix transformationMatrix = new Matrix();
            float focusX = detector.getFocusX();
            float focusY = detector.getFocusY();

            // Zoom focus is where the fingers are centered,
            transformationMatrix.postTranslate(-focusX, -focusY);

            transformationMatrix.postScale(detector.getScaleFactor(),
                    detector.getScaleFactor());

            /*
             * Adding focus shift to allow for scrolling with two pointers down.
             * Remove it to skip this functionality. This could be done in fewer
             * lines, but for clarity I do it this way here
             */
            // Edited after comment by chochim
            float focusShiftX = focusX - lastFocusX;
            float focusShiftY = focusY - lastFocusY;
            transformationMatrix.postTranslate(focusX + focusShiftX, focusY
                    + focusShiftY);
            mMatrix.postConcat(transformationMatrix);
            lastFocusX = focusX;
            lastFocusY = focusY;
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            lastFocusX = detector.getFocusX();
            lastFocusY = detector.getFocusY();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }

    public class GestureListener implements OnGestureListener,
            OnDoubleTapListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (mIsMove) {
                mMatrix.postTranslate(-distanceX, -distanceY);
                invalidate();
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void setMove(boolean isMove) {
        mIsMove = isMove;
    }

    // EA VIKALP

    public void setWarpBitmap(Bitmap bmp) {
        fg = true;// é‡�ç½®æ ‡å¿—
        first = 0;
        mBmp = bmp;
        width = bmp.getWidth();
        height = bmp.getHeight();
        // æ–°å»ºï¿½?ï¿½ï¿½Bitmap
        // SU VIKALP
        // newBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
        // Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        newBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        // EU VIKALP
        image = new int[width * height];

        mBmp.getPixels(image, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
        newBmp.setPixels(image, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
        // super.setImageBitmap(mBmp);
    }

    public void setMode(int mode) {
        this.MODE = mode;
    }

    /**
     * è¿�?å›žå¤„ç�†å¥½çš„å›¾ç‰‡
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public Bitmap getWrapBitmap() {
        return newBmp;
    }

    public void changeBitmapContrastBrightness() {
        float contrast, brightness;
        Random generator = new Random();
        contrast = generator.nextFloat();
        brightness = contrast;

        // Log.i(TAG, "changeBitmapContrastBrightness " + contrast);

        ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(new float[] { 
                0.501f, 0, 0, 0,0,// red
                0, 0, 0, 0, brightness,// green
                0, 0, 0.501f, 0, brightness,// blue
                0, 0, 0, 1, 0 // alpha
                });
        mPaint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
        invalidate();
    }
}
```